# Logic behind the algorithm for converting base 10 to base X

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, base-conversion

What is the rationale behind the below algorithm :

Algorithm to Convert From Decimal To Another Base
Let n be the decimal number.
Let m be the number, initially empty, that we are converting to. We'll be composing it right to left.
Let b be the base of the number we are converting to. 
Repeat until n becomes 0 
   Divide n by b, letting the result be d and the remainder be r. 
   Write the remainder, r, as the leftmost digit of b. 
   Let d be the new value of n.

Answer (score 2):

Statement: the remainder `r` is the last digit of the result.

Indeed, separate `n` into two parts: the part divisible by `r` and the remainder.
We get `n = d * b + r` where `0 <= r < b`.

In base `b`, the notation is `n = c_k * b^k + ... + c_1 * b^1 + c_0 * b^0`.
Since everything except `c_0 * b^0` is divisible by `b`, the equality `r = c_0` follows trivially.

---

For the remaining digits, rewrite

`n = c_k * b^k + ... + c_1 * b^1 + c_0 * b^0`

as

`n = (c_k * b^{k-1} + ... + c_1 * b^0) * b + c_0 * b^0`.

On the other hand,

`n = d * b + r`.

It immediately follows that

`d = c_k * b^{k-1} + ... + c_1 * b^0`.

So, to find all digits except the last, we got to solve the same problem but for `d < n` instead of `n`.
Overall correctness now follows trivially by induction by `n`.